# mvn works in cmd prompt but not in batch

Tags: windows, maven, batch-file, command-line

I am trying to use mvn in a batch script and am encountering the following error when I run the script:

```
'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

However I am able to run mvn from the same directory when I simply use `mvn clean install` from the command prompt.

Info on system environment variables:

```
D:\Projects>echo %JAVA_HOME%
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60
D:\Projects>echo %M2%
C:\Apps\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin
D:\Projects>echo %M2_HOME%
C:\Apps\apache-maven-3.3.3
```

Path:

```
C:\app\212482926\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;%GRADLE_HOME%\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;C:\Sybase\DataAccess\OLEDB\dll;C:\Sybase\DataAccess\ODBC\dll;C:\Sybase\OCS-12_5\lib3p;C:\Sybase\ADO.NET\dll;C:\Sybase\OLEDB;C:\Sybase\ODBC;C:\Sybase\OCS-12_5\dll;C:\Sybase\OCS-12_5\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\apps\Cygwin\bin;C:\Apps\Tcl\bin;C:\Apps\perl\bin;%CSAM_SOCKADAPTER%bin;C:\PROGRA~2\CA\SC\CAM\bin;c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\scala\bin;c:\apps\bin;c:\apps\lib;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;D:\typesafe-activator-1.3.10\activator-dist-1.3.10\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\\bin;C:\apache-ant-1.9.6-bin\apache-ant-1.9.6\bin;%GROOVY_HOME%\bin;C:\%GRADLE_HOME%\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\TextPad 4;C:\Ruby23-x64\bin;D:\gradle-2.13-bin\gradle-2.13\bin;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\SourceGear\Common\DiffMerge\;D:\apps\platform-tools-latest-windows\platform-tools;D:\apps\dependency-check\bin;C:\Program Files\7-Zip;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_module\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin
```

I've also tried using both `mvn clean install` and `call mvn clean install` in the batch file with the same results.

Any help would be welcome - thanks!

Comment: Provide full path to `mvn` or add its parent directory path to the `PATH` system variable. Note that setting it by `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\some\new\path` or `path %PATH%;C:\some\new\path` is valid for the *current `cmd` session* only, so check out the [`setx` command](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) to permanently store the change...

Comment: First M2_HOME is not needed. Apart from that you should download the correct archive. For windows this is of course `zip` file for unix like `tar.gz`. Afterwards you have to add only `WhatEverPath\apache-maven-3.5.3\bin` to your path and that should work. Furthermore have you tried to go into the directory just type `mvn --version` inside the installation directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the path of `mvn` into the environment variable `PATH`.

Comment: Alright - I've added both C:\Apps\apache-maven-3.3.3 and C:\Apps\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin to the path now but unfortunately am still encountering the same results

Comment: @Mikmac how about in a new session, not the current session?